# rstatix package anova_test function gives partial eta squared despite setting effect.size = 'ges'

Tags: r, anova, rstatix

I am not able to obtain eta squared, only partial eta squared, when I use `rstatix::anova_test`.

Example from the iris dataset:

First using `aov`:

```r
aov <- aov(Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width + Species, data = iris)
summary(aov)
             Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value  Pr(>F)    
Sepal.Width   1   1.41    1.41   7.363 0.00746 ** 
Species       2  72.75   36.38 189.651 < 2e-16 ***
Residuals   146  28.00    0.19
```

Then using `sjstats::eta_sq`, if I choose `partial = TRUE` or `FALSE` I get a different effect size, as I would expect.

```r
eta_sq(aov, partial = FALSE) 
         term etasq
1 Sepal.Width 0.014
2     Species 0.712

eta_sq(aov, partial = TRUE)
         term partial.etasq
1 Sepal.Width         0.048
2     Species         0.722
```

However, when I do the same in `anova_test`, I get the partial eta squared both times regardless of whether the effect size is pes or ges, both times it's the partial eta squared:

```r
aov_pes <- iris %>% anova_test(Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width + Species,
                               detailed = T,
                               effect.size = "pes")
get_anova_table(aov_pes)

       Effect    SSn    SSd DFn DFd       F        p p<.05
1 Sepal.Width 10.953 28.004   1 146  57.102 4.19e-12     *
2     Species 72.752 28.004   2 146 189.651 2.56e-41     *
    pes
1 0.281
2 0.722

aov_ges <- iris %>% anova_test(Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width + Species,
                               detailed = T,
                               effect.size = "ges")
get_anova_table(aov_ges)

       Effect    SSn    SSd DFn DFd       F        p p<.05
1 Sepal.Width 10.953 28.004   1 146  57.102 4.19e-12     *
2     Species 72.752 28.004   2 146 189.651 2.56e-41     *
    ges
1 0.281
2 0.722
```

Does anyone know why this is? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**Answer**

`rstatix::anova_test` seems to contain a mistake in the calculation! I would be very, very careful with this function.

Note that `eta_sq` is deprecated, and `effectsize::eta_squared` should be used.

---

**Proper calculation**

We have three SS values: 1.412238, 72.752431, and 28.003665. We can calculate the pes and ges:

- pes: 1.412238 / (1.412238 + 28.003665)
- ges: 1.412238 / (1.412238 + 72.752431 + 28.003665)

---

**anova_test**

Under the hood, `anova_test` calls two functions for pes and ges calculation:

- pes: `rstatix:::add_partial_eta_squared`
- ges: `rstatix:::add_generalized_eta_squared`

---

**The pes calculation by `anova_test`**

```r
res.anova.summary$ANOVA %>% mutate(pes = .data$SSn/(.data$SSn + .data$SSd))
```

This indeed calculates the pes as we expect it to.

---

**The ges calculation by `anova_test`**

```r
aov.table <- res.anova.summary$ANOVA
aov.table %>% mutate(ges = .data$SSn/(.data$SSn + sum(unique(.data$SSd)) + obs.SSn1 - obs.SSn2))
```

Here, we run into a problem. This code seems blatantly incorrect. It just divides each sum of square value by itself + the residual sum of squares (28.004). That is the pes, not the ges.

You could contact the maintainer of the package (`maintainer("rstatix")`) or create a new issue for the `rstatix` package [here](https://github.com/kassambara/rstatix/issues).